# Google Sign In For Web Migration to Google Identity Services

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-signin, google-identity

I have a single page web application that uses [Google Sign-In for Web](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) that is [being deprecated](https://developers.googleblog.com/2021/08/gsi-jsweb-deprecation.html). I have followed the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/migration) and logging in works as expected.

However, when the app restarts I used to run the following code:

```
auth2.currentUser.get().reloadAuthResponse().then(function (authResponse) {
    // User still logged into Google
    // Update using authResponse.id_token
}, function (data) {
    // Handle user logged out of Google
});
```

In the [reference section of the migration guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/migration#object_migration_reference_for_user_sign-in) it says for GoogleUser.reloadAuthResponse() the action is to "Remove. An ID token has replaced OAuth2 access tokens and scopes.".

I've looked through the documentation and I haven't seen a way to check if the user is still logged in that is similar to reloadAuthResponse. What way should I replace this?